# Using HTML5 Appcache to "force" offline state

Tags: html, cordova, backbone.js, html5-appcache

When I load my application the first time it downloads the files thats in my CACHE list as seen below. The second time I load the page I want to load it as if it is offline, which I thought is the way it would have worked.

When I disable my internet, the page loads really fast, as is expected, but when online, it still seems to load from the net.

Is there a way to force it to load AS IF IT IS OFFLINE ?

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
http://foo.com/index.html
http://foo.com/foo.html
http://foo.com/foo.jpg
http://foo.com/bar.jpg
http://foo.com/base.css
etc...

NETWORK:
*
```

Comment: Read for how the Appcache works here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293684/ssl-path-in-appcache-network-being-restricted-in-chrome

Answer (score 1):

The picture is from the [SSL path in appcache network being restricted in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293684/ssl-path-in-appcache-network-being-restricted-in-chrome), but just leave it here, it is so cool.

[image]

Comment: Very nice. But where would the block fit in "ALREADY CACHED" -> DONT LOAD AGAIN

Comment: Let's write it in line (we believe the page was already appcached): `GET request` -> `Is request URL associated with a manifest?` -> `Is URL appcached?` -> `Request from cache` -> `Is HTML?` -> `For each GET ...` **+ `Request manifest`**. So in this scheme atleast one GET request sends if online. So, if all content will be cached, the time difference between the online and offline states will be the time of appcache manifest file download.